# no transparency on image

Tags: html, css

So I have this image which im going to call example. So example has a transparency layer like the checker board thing on the image itself. When I do

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">

    .outerLink 
    {
        background-color:black; 
        display:block; 
        opacity:1;
        filter:alpha(opacity=100);
        width:200px;
    }

    img.darkableImage 
    {
        opacity:1;
        filter:alpha(opacity=100);
    }
```

```
<body>
    <a href="/example" class="outerLink">
        <img src="example.png" width="200" 
        class="darkableImage" onmouseout="this.style.opacity=1;this.filters.alpha.opacity=100" 
        onmouseover="this.style.opacity=0.6;this.filters.alpha.opacity=60" />
    </a>
</body>
```

it removes the transparency and it looks like:

[image]

how do i get the transparency back?

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: It seems to work fine for me (http://jsfiddle.net/qw5poow4/) so the problem is somewhere else.